# This regex works in php but dont works in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am using this code in php:

```
php:

elseif (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,31}$/', $username))
{
    echo "user name is not valid";
}
else
{
    echo "user name is OK!";
}
```

but I want use like this in java scipt:

```
javascript:

if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,31}$/', username))
{
document.getElementById("u_status").innerHTML="user name is not valid";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("u_status").innerHTML="user name is OK";
}
```

please help me to use this rejex in javascript

Comment: Do you just want to convert the code from PHP to JS?

Comment: I took the liberty to changing your title by changing `java` to `javascript`, since this is what your question is about,

Comment: Our solution didn't help you ? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not contain a `preg_match` function, what it does have is a [`match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) function.

Thus, this line `if(!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,31}$/', username))` needs to be changed to `if(!username.match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,31}$/')) {`

Answer (score 0):

A String object in javascript has a `match()` function that will help you:

```
if(!username.match(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,31}$/)){

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- use `String#match` instead of `preg_match()`
- use directly `/<regex>/` instead of `'/<regex>/'`

Try this:

```
if(!username.match(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,31}$/){
    document.getElementById("u_status").innerHTML="user name is not valid";
} else {
    document.getElementById("u_status").innerHTML="user name is OK";
}
```